# Asking for helps about deriving arcsine distribution

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

[image]

I solved the above exercise. And the exercise below is based on the exercise above.

[image]

Here, I managed to show the first equality of (i). But I can't find a way how to prove the second equality of (i) at all. Also, I tried to solve (ii) first by using Stirling formula. But, the calculations only get complicated and I can't get the required result. Now I am totally stuck..
Could anyone please help me how to solve this exercise 2? or at least give me some hints?